# Having trouble installing zxcvbn

Tags: passwords, java, programming

I'm a high school student conducting a science fair project that analyzes the strength of the average person's password. I've decided to use the Java version of zxcvbn, **nbvcxz**, to estimate password strength. I decided on the Java version because I'm taking an intro Computer Science class, and we've been using Dr.Java to write programs.

For the past several weeks, I have collected data by asking individuals to generate a password that they considered "adequately secure," and now have a list of around 50 passwords. My goal is to create some program that, when inputted the list, takes each password and converts it to a numerical value based on the rating that nbvcxz assigns it.

Unfortunately, I have no prior experience using anything similar to nbvcxz and am unsure how to install it. The instructions, found [here](https://github.com/GoSimpleLLC/nbvcxz#standalone), seem simple, but I'm not quite sure how to "compile" it first.

I am also unsure how to create a program that will do what I described, and would appreciate any pointers or recommendations on where to find information. Is Java even the right language to use in this situation?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Help installing software is off-topic here. Even if it were, you do not say what you tried and what doesn't work. If you're confused about compiling, `java -jar nbvcxz-1.4.0.jar` does both the compiling and the running.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried entering that command into CMD, but it comes back with an error (Error: Unable to access jarfile nbvcxz-1.4.0.jar). I assumed this was because I hadn't compiled. Also, where would you recommend that I post this for extra help?

Comment: What's your goal? To write a program or to analyse passwords? There are many online tools to do this, so I assume the goal is to program? Java can do this, so can any other language. You went with Java because of that library, and that's fine. Your question here is entirely a programming question with a Java basics question, which is off-topic.

Comment: that error you are getting is a permissions error or the location where you are running it cannot find the file